# Neovim - using patched nerdfont but icon not working

Tags: neovim

I am using neovim 0.9.  I liked JetBrains Mono font so I downloaded the nerd font patched JetBrains font and installed on my Linux Mint 21.1.  All is well except when there is an error, neovim displays this weird icon if the linter/checker gets an error.

How can I fix this?

[image]

Update 6/13/23

I think I am missing an icon set.  Do you know where I can get this icons?

[image]

Comment: Are you using the GUI version of Vim (gVim) or the terminal one (vim)? In the later case did you change the terminal font or the Vim font or both?

Comment: i am using the terminal version.  i've set the terminal font.

Comment: What is the value of the `guifont` (`set guifont?`). What if you use `:set guifont=?`?

Comment: May be could you accept your own answer using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.  I've installed the font manager app and copied icons I liked from the font into the setting file.  It works.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up!